# How do I replace all commas with comma spaces (pep8)?

Tags: python, unix, vim

I wrote some Python code and unfortunately forgot a few spaces after commas (trying to follow Pep8). How can I replace the commas with commas followed by spaces. The trick here is that some commas already have spaces, so if I do a simple search and replace, some commas will be followed by double spaces. And if I replace double spaces with single spaces then my tabs (which expand to spaces) will get messed up.

I am looking for the appropriate vim command and if possible the appropriate unix command too. I am trying to do this to follow pep8. Is there anything that can autocorrect stylistic errors to follow pep8? I've found modules that identify errors, but do not fix them.

Comment: This should do it https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vim substitution:

```
:%s/,\([^ ]\)/, \1/g
```

The leading `^` in the `[]` character class, says not this. So it, `[^ ]`, matches anything that's not a space.

EDIT, was deleting things after the space. The `\(\)` saves stuff, and the `\1` returns that.

Comment: Right, and replaces it with a space.

Answer (score 5):

**Python Solution**:

```
my_new_string = my_old_string.replace(',', ', ').replace(',  ', ', ')
```

If you want to run this on a file:

```
f = open('path/to/file')
my_file_contents = f.read()
f.close()
f = open('path/to/file', 'w')
f.write(file_contents.replace(',', ', ').replace(',  ', ', '))
```

**`vim` Solution**:

```
:%s/,\ */,\ /g
```

Comment: True. I saw the `python` tag an got excited.

Comment: Note that this will be quite dangerous for any file where a comma might be inside a string, for example `','.join(someList)`, so better use with care.

Comment: @poke I don't think a regex will be able to handle the cases you're referring to. Nothing but a language parser is going to be able to get at that.

Comment: @kjprice Wasn’t suggesting to use a parser or anything, just to be careful when doing this and maybe double checking the changes afterwards :)

Comment: @kjprice: Wonder if PyLint would have a way to "transform" non compliant code. Since it has a paser built-in and all...

Answer (score 2):

As far as autocorrecting errors goes, [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8) is great for this - it ships with a binary that you can use to correct errors in place, although I'm afraid I don't know how you'd tie it into vim.

Answer (score 2):

For a one-off replacement in vim:

```
:%s/\v,(\S)/, \1/g
```

But do use a vim plugin.